Getting 'No operations defined in spec!' for SpringDoc Swagger
I have implemented swagger using the OpenAPI library.
My application is running on spring boot 2.7.1
I'm getting 'No operations defined in spec!', even my controller is having api's. What could be the problem.
Here is the code.
OrderController.java
package com.example.service;

import com.example.service.Order;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.tags.Tag;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/orders")
@Tag(name = "contact", description = "the Contact API")
public class OrderController {
    
    //System.out.println("OrderController");

    @PostMapping("/orders")
    public int saveOrderDetails(@RequestBody Order order) {
        int orderId = 1;
        return orderId;
    }

    @Operation(summary = "Find Contacts by name", description = "Name search by %name% format", tags = { "contact" })
    @GetMapping(value = "/orders/{orderId}", produces = { "application/json", "application/xml" })
    public Order getOrderDetails(@RequestParam("orderId") int orderId) {
        Order order = new Order();
        return order;
    }

    @PutMapping("/orders")
    public ResponseEntity<String> updateOrderDetails(@RequestBody Order order) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Updated successfully",
                HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/orders")
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteOrderDetails(@RequestParam("orderId") int orderId) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Deleted successfully",
                HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
}

Application.java
public class Application {

    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws VtmException 
    {
              SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
         }

        @Bean
   public OpenAPI vOpenAPI() {
       
    
       return new OpenAPI()
               .info(new Info().title("Advanced REST API")
               .description("REST API application"))
               .components(new Components());
   }

pom.xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency> 

application.Proterties
springdoc.packagesToScan=com.example.service
springdoc.pathsToMatch=/vtm/v1

# swagger-ui custom path
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html

# /api-docs endpoint custom path
springdoc.api-docs.path=/v3/api-docs

springdoc.api-docs.enabled=true

Tried to get output in the swagger but getting ''No operations defined in spec!'
I'm expecting to get correct output in swagger for the apis.

Just remove ‘springdoc.pathsToMatch=/vtm/v1’ this will only allow operations with ‘/vfm/v1’  in request mapping.

Remove all these config in your application.properties because these are useless in your case
springdoc.pathsToMatch=/vtm/v1
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html
springdoc.api-docs.path=/v3/api-docs
springdoc.api-docs.enabled=true



remove this bean from main Application class . Because it is trying to add new empty component
 @Bean
   public OpenAPI vOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI()
               .info(new Info().title("Advanced REST API")
               .description("REST API application"))
               .components(new Components());
   }

